# How are batched DWR requests handled differently from non-batched on the server side?

Tags: python, ajax, dwr

I've written a DWR client in Python, which I use for automating tests run against a DWR-based website.  Up until now, all the calls I make are single, non-batched requests, and I make several requests, all in a single-threaded manner.

I noticed that when I use a browser, some of the calls are batched up into a single request.  Aside from the bundling, are there any differences with how the calls are handled by the server?  I believe they're parsed back out and handled serially, and from what I've tested, there are no noticeable differences.  However, I'm concerned there might be some hidden pitfalls, and I need my python client to simulate browser usage.

Comment: Would you share tip on how to create a DWR client in python?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In almost all cases, batching acts the same way as a bunch of synchronous unbatched calls.  See the Caveats section of [DWR Batching](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/browser/engine/batch.html) for potential pitfalls.